# If devils are locked up in Ramadan, why do some Muslims still sin during the month?

Tags: ramadan, shaitan, behavior

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Apostle said, "When the month of
>   Ramadan starts, the gates of the heaven are opened and the gates of
>   Hell are closed and the devils are chained. -" Sahih Bukhari 31:123

If devils are locked up in Ramadan how is that some Muslims still sin during the month? How is sinning during Ramadan different than sinning in other months?

Comment: I cannot believe that no one answered about the NAFS. Your nafs leads you to commit sins aswell as shaitan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The complete hadith is as following:

Narrated Abu Hurairah (radiallahu ta’ala anhu): Allah’s Messenger (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) said,

> “When the month of Ramadan comes, the gates of Paradise are opened and
>   the gates of (Hell) Fire are closed, and the devils are chained.”
>   **[Sahih al Bukhaari #3277]**

There are many types of Shayateen with varying levels of wickedness.

1. Those who reside in the toilets are known as **Khubuth**:

   > “Anas reported that when the Messenger of Allah (salallahu alayhi
   >   wassalam) entered the  privy he  would say, "In the name of Allah. O
   >   Allah! I seek refuge in you from male  (khubuth) and  female
   >   (khabaa’ith) noxious beings (devils)." **(Bukhari & Muslim)**
2. Those who disturb us in the prayer are called **Khinzaab**: 
   Narrated Uthman ibn Abul'As: Uthman came to Allah's Messenger (salallahu alayhi wassalam) and said:

   > Allah's Messenger, the Satan intervenes between me and my prayer and
   >   my reciting of the  Qur'an and he confounds me. Thereupon Allah's
   >   Messenger (peace be upon him) said: “That is (the doing of the Satan)
   >   who is known as Khinzab, and when you perceive its  effect, seek
   >   refuge with Allah from it and spit three times to your left.” I did
   >   that and Allah  dispelled that from me. **(Sahih Muslim, Ahmad, Abu
   >   Dawood)**
3. The one who are more wicked than the Shaytaan is called **Maarid**:

   > “And to guard against every rebellious devil (Shaytaan maarid).”
   >   **[Suran al-Saaffaat (37):7]**
4. The most strong amongst them is called **'Ifreet**:

   > “(Sulaymaan) said (to his own men): "O Chiefs! Which of you can bring
   >   me her throne  before they come to me in submission?" An  'Ifreet
   >   (strong one) from the jinn said: "I will bring it to you before you
   >   rise from your place (council). And verily, I am indeed strong and
   >   trustworthy for such work." One with whom was knowledge of the
   >   Scripture said: "I will bring it to you within the twinkling of an
   >   eye!" Then when (Sulaymaan) saw it placed firmly before him he said:
   >   "This is by the grace of my Lord! to test me whether I am grateful or
   >   ungrateful! And if any is grateful truly his gratitude is (a gain) for
   >   his own soul; but if any is ungrateful truly my Lord is Free of All
   >   Needs Supreme in Honor!"  **[Surah al-Naml (27): 38-40]**

   And there are more types of shayateen like these.

Coming to the question,

Shakyh Abdur-Rahmaan bin Naasir as-Sa’di (rahimuhullaah) said in the chapter “Baab us-Siyaam” (Chapter of Fasting) in his book Minhaj as Saalikeen (translated to English):

> As the Gates of Jannah are being opened at the same time the Gates of
>   Jahannam are being closed.The Shayaateen are in levels, Iblis being at
>   the top and then the Khabith next and the small shayateen. **Iblis and
>   the Khabith shayateen (May Allaahs Curse be upon them until The Hour),
>   the Maarid (sick ones) are locked up but the small shayateen are not
>   locked up**; hence why you see some small evil in Ramadhaan. The strong
>   shayateen called maarid, they are also being locked up and chained in
>   the month of Ramadhaan.

Hence, these small shayateen try to trap us and we choose to fall into it and sin. May Allah save us from that.

**Reference:**

- [Devils chained during Ramadan?](http://shayaateen.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/devils-chained-during-ramadan/)
- [Jinns.](http://www.salafitalk.net/st/uploads/Jinns1.pdf)

Comment: You also have nafs, which encourage you to sin.

Comment: I understand there are different kinds of them but what hadith suggests that some shayateen are not locked up?

Comment: @HasanKhan It is known that there are shayateen among human beings as well. They are not locked up (as we can see humans are not chained). Only leaders of the shayateen are chained. The shayateen among Ins (human) remain (but weakened because their leaders are chained). The leaders of shayateen that are among the Jinn are chained. Due to these shayateen among human, they create traps for us and our nafs falls for it. And Allah knows the best.

Answer (score 5):

It's simpler that that. In Islam it's not just the devil who are the sources of sins.
The person itself can be the source of the sin which is in Arabic "annfaess el amara bel sou".

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the long term effect that Satan leaves on us. Committing a sin becomes a habit and even when Satan is chained we still tend to commit some sins that have become our habit.
This is what I think and rest Allah knows the best.

Answer (score 1):

What if Allah chains them to help us but also let us free them if we insist on the desire? This has a witness from Quran as well:

> For each (such person) there are (angels) in succession, before and
>   behind him: They guard him by command of Allah. Allah does not change
>   a people's lot unless they change what is in their hearts. But when
>   (once) Allah willeth a people's punishment, there can be no turning it
>   back, nor will they find, besides Him, any to protect. [13:11]

People have an inside devil, right, but one who insist on a forbidden desire would find the devils set free to affect them, and of course insisting on the desire is inspired by the inside devil. God will never force us not to do sin, although he may always help us and this helping is more bold during Ramadan!

Godspeed

Answer (score -1):

It's the way of presenting things. In the philosophical way:  "the gates of the heaven are opened and the gates of Hell are closed." means we are suppose to do good things and avoid bad things.

Comment: Please back up your argument with reference if you could.

Answer (score -4):

Yo brother I know this is a bit late but consider a cup of tea and your the tea and the shaytan is the spoon when you stir the cup of tea and then you remove the teaspoon it keeps stirring eventually it will die down and the tea would come flat but that's how it's like all the shaytans are locked up during Ramadan know its a bit late but hope it helps ramadan Kareem brother Salam

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE. We suggest you read the FAQ. Answers are expected to have citations from Quran, Sunnah, Fatwas or other reliable Islamic resource. Your answer has no citations