# Nightmare during Ramadan

Tags: hadith, ramadan, shaitan, dream

I cite from [Islam Q&A](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/9577)

> It was reported from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Towards the end of time, hardly any dreams that the Muslim sees will not come true. The one whose dreams are the most truthful will be the one whose speech is the most honest. The dreams of the Muslim form one of the forty-five parts of Prophecy. Dreams are of three types: the good dream which is good news from Allah; dreams which cause distress, which come from the Shaytaan; and dreams concerning matters which a person is thinking about…” (Narrated by Muslim, 2263)
>
> It was reported that Abu Qutaadah said: “The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: ‘Good dreams come from Allah and bad dreams come from the Shaytaan. If any one of you sees a bad dream which makes him afraid, let him spit drily to his left and seek refuge with Allah from its evil, then it will not harm him.” (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 3118; Muslim, 2261).

So I had one of the most horrific dreams, which included blood, gore and violence that I never think about. I'm doing research during summer, very far away from the things I dreamt and I never recall any dreams like that, not even similar. If the above two hadith are authentic, then my dream must come from shaytaan.

However, according to this hadith, shaytaans are locked up during Ramadan.

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Apostle said, "When the month of Ramadan starts, the gates of the heaven are opened and the gates of Hell are closed and the devils are chained. -" Sahih Bukhari 31:123

So how do you explain this? One or both of the hadith are not true? Or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for [dream interpretation](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/780/17163).

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to comment on the subject of the dreams since I don't get dreams like that (Alhamdulilah) neither I know anything about that subject. But, as I understand the question, it boils down to the fact that when shayateen are chained in Ramadaan, why does evil stuff still happens.

It is related to another question that I had put up an answer before - [If devils are locked up in Ramadan how is that some Muslims still sin during the month?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1303/38). Quoting from the answer -

Shakyh Abdur-Rahmaan bin Naasir as-Sa’di (rahimuhullaah) said in the chapter “Baab us-Siyaam” (Chapter of Fasting) in his book Minhaj as Saalikeen (translated to English):

> As the Gates of Jannah are being opened at the same time the Gates of
>   Jahannam are being closed.The Shayaateen are in levels, Iblis being at
>   the top and then the Khabith next and the small shayateen. Iblis and
>   the Khabith shayateen (May Allaahs Curse be upon them until The Hour),
>   the Maarid (sick ones) are locked up but the small shayateen are not
>   locked up; hence why you see some small evil in Ramadhaan. The strong
>   shayateen called maarid, they are also being locked up and chained in
>   the month of Ramadhaan.

I hope that answers your question. If I didn't understand your question properly, let me know, I will delete my answer.

Comment: You answer is valid. However, I in general do not trust people who claim to know the unseen. What source does Shakyh Abdur-Rahmaan bin Naasir as-Sa’di have, if it is not from Quran or hadith? Where can he possibly learn that?

Comment: @mezhang He doesn't claim to know the unseen. The Shaykh is one of the famous contemporary mufassarin (Tafsir As Sa'adi). It is a scholarly interpretation. There are other scholarly interpretations on the same lines. One being that the leaders of Devils are chained and their soldiers are weak (because their leaders are chained). This is the opinion of Shaykh Ubayd al-Jaabiree. The scholars try to reconcile two hadiths. Allahu A'lam.

Comment: Here are similar scholarly interpretations - http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/37965, http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/39736

Answer (score 0):

This is somthing I heard a long time ago.

The shaytaans are chained that means they still have a distance in communication they can still influence but very little because there voices may or can be heard accasionely. And Allah knows best

Comment: please consider: http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

It is the nafs that results in sins during Ramadan as well...I do not know regarding dreams but the nafs is enough to lead us astray as Shaytan has had 11 months to prepare it for disobedience to ALLAH.

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum brother, we welcome you to Islam. SE, Please take a look at our [Site](http://islam.stackexchange.com/about) and see [how the things are going on this site](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help) before answering. Add some references from Quran/Hadith to make your answer helpful to others. Jazakallahu Hair