# Is the shaytan released right before Eid or after?

Tags: ramadan, hadith-interpretation, shaitan

There are numerous examples in the hadith literature referring to the fact that during the month of Ramadan, the shaytan is chained.  For example, as narrated by Abu Hurayrah and transmitted through Bukhari,

> [Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "When the month of Ramadan starts, the gates of the heaven are opened and the gates of Hell are closed and the devils are chained."](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/30/9)

This does however leave me with a question regarding this tradition: When is the shaytan released from hell?  Is it right before or after the Eid day?

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/if-devils-are-locked-up-in-ramadan-how-is-that-some-muslims-still-sin-during-the

Comment: Well first of all, Satan isn't looked in hell. When moon of Ramadan sights, Allah order angle to chain Satan and throw them in the sea.

Answer (score -1):

They are released on the 27th of Ramadan. When laylatul Qadr starts. Please make dua againts them to weaken them and their plots. Jazakllahu kharain

Answer (score -3):

Shaytan are tied down for the month of Ramazan. The Ramazan ends on the night before the Eid day as, in islamic calender, the next day starts when the sun sets. So the shaytan should be released when the sun sets on the previous day of Eid.