# Does magic work on a person during ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, jinn, sihr

As it is known, the jinn are locked up during the blessed month of Ramadan. We also know that people perform magic (or sihir) on others out of jealousy etc. To perform magic however, the assistance of jinn is needed.

My question is if someone had black magic performed on them, will this magic continue to work during the month of Ramadan?

Also, is 'ain (the evil eye) the same thing, and does that also work during Ramadan (or at least its effects).

Another word, I just wanted to say Ramadan Mubarak to all, may Allah (SWT) forgive all our sins and shower us and all our loved ones with mercy and blessings in this beautiful month.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are not intended for argument and debate, and especially not for attacking the belief systems of other users.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct as a famous issue that you mentioned

> As it is known, the jinn are locked up during the blessed month of
>   Ramadan.

But, to the best of my knowledge, these could be two different and separated issues. I mean the issue of "the jinn are locked up during the blessed month of Ramadan." would be true as it has narrated as a hadith (if it is considered as an authentic hadith), but black magic or Sihr can be considered as another matter which I infer it can be done even in Ramadan as well. But in regard to the first matter as you mentioned

> As it is known, the jinn are locked up during the blessed month of
>   Ramadan.

It could be inferred from the hadith that we should pay more heed that in this month (Ramadan al Mubarak) they are locked during it and whatever you do (committing sins) would be from yourselves not Shaitan. But probably other items are going to be done based on the routine rules. (Wallah o A'lamo)

Comment: jazaakullah kheir on your answer, it does help, but I still dont understand how the magic can work without the assistance of jinn.

Comment: Your welcome. are you familiar in Arabic (Or Farsi)? if so, I reckon the following site can help you http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa2068  of course it is available in Turkey, French, and Indonesia as well if you know one of them

Comment: See also: "[If devils are locked up in Ramadan how is that some Muslims still sin during the month?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1300/9123)"

Comment: oops, yeah. it can be helpful as a constructive issue as well. Well done.

Comment: jazaakullah kheir brothers :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a victim of black magic, from my experience I can tell you that black magic still works during Ramadhan. And not all jinn's are locked up in Ramadhan.